# Need for character escaping in Apache FilesMatch

Tags: regex, apache

should the dot character be escaped in this situation:

```
<FilesMatch "^/(app.csv|translation.csv*)$">
   FileETag None
   Header unset ETag
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
   Header set Pragma "no-cache"
   Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Such as:

```
<FilesMatch "^/(app\.csv|translation\.csv*)$">
```

Or is Apache able to understand that this is a file extension?

Comment: Whenever it comes to regular expressions, a dot should be escaped to mean a literal character. Yes, you should escape it.

Comment: Thanks, should I also start the line with ^ ?